# Side-By-Side Pie Charts With ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, pie-chart, facet

My data has values of 5 years across different geographic regions, and I am trying to generate a side-by-side pie chart showing Regions share for each year.

I tried the below code, seems like it works fine but the pie charts are not complete. Please check the image:[Link to the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtU0A.png)

[image]

I am not sure what am I missing, any help is much appreciated!

This is the code I used:

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

test1<-melt(comp)

ggplot(test1, aes(x = factor(1), y = value, fill = factor(variable))) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) + 
theme(legend.position = "none") +
scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0,0)) +
scale_y_continuous(NULL, expand = c(0,0)) + 
coord_polar(theta = "y") +
facet_wrap(~Year)
```

Here's the data I used:

```
comp<-structure(list(World = c(169, 187, 210, 226, 232, 261, 245, 223, 
195, 174, 154, 163, 195, 221, 240, 264, 283, 296, 269, 256, 231, 
214, 201, 171, 200, 216, 234, 253, 282, 305, 296, 279, 266, 243, 
232, 203, 216, 239, 266, 284, 315, 340, 319, 304, 277, 250, 228, 
213, 240, 251, 281, 298, 322, 350, 330, 311, 289, 265, 239, 219
), `NA` = c(102, 115, 128, 136, 137, 151, 140, 128, 103, 96, 
84, 99, 123, 141, 152, 163, 178, 170, 153, 146, 131, 125, 118, 
96, 112, 117, 126, 138, 152, 163, 156, 148, 143, 131, 128, 107, 
110, 123, 138, 150, 169, 181, 169, 160, 141, 123, 112, 105, 121, 
126, 148, 155, 168, 183, 170, 158, 149, 136, 121, 108), SA = c(12, 
13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 18, 16, 15, 14, 11, 9, 10, 13, 16, 20, 22, 
28, 25, 23, 20, 16, 13, 11, 15, 18, 20, 23, 26, 30, 28, 26, 24, 
21, 18, 15, 19, 23, 26, 30, 33, 37, 34, 32, 29, 26, 24, 23, 26, 
28, 31, 35, 39, 43, 41, 38, 33, 30, 26, 23), Eur = c(52, 55, 
61, 67, 73, 82, 80, 76, 73, 62, 59, 54, 59, 62, 66, 70, 75, 86, 
81, 79, 73, 68, 66, 61, 66, 71, 76, 79, 85, 91, 89, 86, 82, 76, 
73, 70, 74, 79, 83, 88, 91, 95, 92, 90, 87, 83, 77, 74, 80, 82, 
85, 89, 95, 98, 95, 93, 89, 85, 80, 76), Pac = c(3, 4, 6, 7, 
5, 9, 7, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 11, 8, 12, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 
4, 6, 9, 11, 14, 15, 18, 15, 13, 12, 10, 7, 8, 10, 13, 11, 15, 
19, 17, 15, 14, 12, 10, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 12, 15, 14, 13, 11, 
8, 7, 7), China = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
4, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 8, 11, 10, 
9, 7, 6, 5, 5), Year = c("2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2011", 
"2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", 
"2011", "2011", "2011", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014")), class =     
"data.frame", row.names = 3:62)
```

Comment: try adding `position = "fill"` to the `geom_bar`

Comment: thank you @RichardTelford it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple issues.

First, you're comparing `World` as though it's a region just like China or Europe or anything else. I'm almost certain you want to add up just regions, so when I reshape this into long data, I'm taking out the `World` column. You could instead choose to keep it and just omit it from `gather`, if you need to make reference to it later.

Second, you have a column called `NA`. That's a bad idea, since `NA` has a very specific meaning in R. For now I'm renaming it `no_name`, but maybe it's North America?

Third, there's no mechanism here for the bars adding up to a whole circle, so they don't. Use `position = "fill"` when you make the bars.

Also `geom_col` is equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`, and especially since I needed to make sure bars add up correctly, I thought `geom_col` would be safer.

In the first version, bars are just stacked and you can probably see borders between the wedges. This is kinda ugly in my opinion, so for the second, I first added up values for each year and region.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_long <- df %>%
  rename(no_name = `NA`) %>%
  select(-World) %>%
  gather(key = region, value = value, -Year)

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = factor(1), y = value, fill = region)) +
  geom_col(width = 1, position = "fill") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  facet_wrap(~ Year) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = F)
```

[image]

```r
df_sums <- df_long %>%
  group_by(Year, region) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value))

ggplot(df_sums, aes(x = factor(1), y = value, fill = region)) +
  geom_col(width = 1, position = "fill") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  facet_wrap(~ Year) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = F)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).